# Method Not Found Error at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime, nuget

I have a project that make a call to a method in another library. When I run locally everything works. Once I deploy to dev server, the method in the other library is not found and causes a runtime error. I have checked the library has property to Copy Local set to true. I checked the version of the file locally and on dev server and they match. The library was added through NuGet and is the most recent version.

Any ideas what would cause the method to not be found after being published?

EDIT: The library is company library on private nuget server

Comment: Is it something in the GAC?  The name of the library could be helpful.

Comment: if you have a hierarchical folder structure in you bin folder, make sure you don't have additional copies of the DLL in else where in the bin.

Comment: Sounds like you are attempting to call a method on a class in the company library that is not present in the version that is out on the dev server. If it is a company maintained library, someone may have neglected to update the version information after adding the method you need, making it appear to be the same version (just going by the version numbers) when, in reality, it is not. As as additional check you can check to see if the file sizes match between the library on your local workstation and one on the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

Try JustDecompile or another decompilation tool to check the content of your DLL on the dev system. Maybe (as said before by Biscuits) it's a GAC problem.